# .Net MAUI keep app alive in the background without a service - Android

Tags: xamarin.forms, monodevelop, maui

.NET Maui (Android)
I need to keep an app playing music in the background even if it's not focused.

I searched and found most research redirects to use a service.

I do many calculations and I call APIs on regular bases to update the stream so I'm not sure if using a service is the best choice as I need to stay connected with the stream from the app.

I tired to override OnPause as following

```
  protected override void OnPause()
    {
        base.OnPause();
    }
```

But not sure if that will do the trick

Comment: to play music in the background on Android you need to write an Android service

Comment: @Jason so using a service is the best practice? I can't keep the app running in the background.

Comment: This is the specific mechanism Android provides to run in the background.

Comment: @Jason Thanks, I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: You can check this doc [Foreground Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/), then try to implement a version of Android- MAUI. Also, you can learn how to [play mp3](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/7458) in Android MAUI.

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT I know it and I'm already using it now, it's just not a simple mp3 to play so I was hoping to find another way.
Thank you for taking the time to answer.